# Login failed for user during update-database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a big problem. I tried to use another solution but didn't help me.
I try to make initial migration (code-first workflow) to database which is on my computer.
I used commands in PM like enable-migrations, then add-migration *NameMigration*, then update-database and at this moment I have an error like:

```
Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11
Cannot open database "CodeFirstDemo.Program+BlogDbContext" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'SZYMON\Szymon'.
```

My config:

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BlogDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=SZYMON\BASE; Initial Catalog=CodeFirstDemo; Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Database is not exist yet. My object explorer in MS SQL Server looks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eo9a6.png)

Server properties looks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaBjN.png)

I don't know what is wrong. Please help me to solve problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a lot of things that can cause this.  However, the first thing is to confirm whether the SZYMON\szymon Account has the rights, in the database, sql server and host server to do this.

Comment: Ok?  What did you notice?

Comment: @RBarryYoung I noticed something. I clicked Properties of server(SZYMON\BASE) -> View connection properties and in section Authentication in user name I have: Authentication method: Windows Authentication User name: MicrosoftAccount\somethinganotherthanSZYMON\Szymon@outlook.com Is it correct? Additionally i I tested DB first workflow with the same server and there is no problem.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I checked this. Still cannot update database, I get errot like in description. What can I check in next step?

Comment: Can you connect to the database using a tool like SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)?  Try it from the same client to the same server.  If you can, try it both with your normal admin/dev account and then with your application's login.

Comment: Alternatively, if your client program can normally connect (outside of update-database) using that account, then it might need advanced permissions in the database like `dbowner` to do the migration.

Comment: Yes, I can connect to the database by SSMS.
I solved the problem, but I don't understand a bit. I created new app only and it works.
It is very confusing.

Comment: the user must be created from a windows account on SQL Server, first.
Then the user must be granted administrative privileges on SQL to create a database.

Comment: also the PC and the SQL Server must be on the same Windows Active Directory domain, lest this won't work.  I hate EF for more reasons than all the glaring security problems

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem that you have access to the database server. Try to login using SQL Management Studio to SZYMON\BASE db server using windows authentication.

Comment: I chcecked. I can log in to server SZYMON\BASE with windows authentication where I use user name SZYMON\Szymon, so this point seems OK.